# Do I need the kernel source for module programming?

Tags: c, kernel-module, kernel

I am trying to get into kernel module programming. After some research, I am in a bit of confusion. My question is, do I need a kernel source for doing module programming?

Also if yes, do I need to recompile the kernel after I have compiled the modules I have written?

Comment: You do not have to recompile the kernel (unless it doesn't support modules.) That's the whole point of kernel modules!

Comment: Besdies, why do you care? Are you having a problem? If so, then you can fix the problem. Otherwise, just get started and try it!!

Comment: @JonathonReinhart but I do need the source ?

Comment: I don't know, do you? Probably not. You must likely just need the headers (a `kernel-devel` package or something similar.)  There are dozens of pages out there on kernel module tutorials. Just get started and try one! You're wasting time that could be spent learning!

Comment: You'll almost certainly need the source, but only in that you'll be using it to reference included modules' source.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Do I need a kernel source for doing module programming ?

You need the kernel header files, normally I use:
$  sudo apt-get install build-essential linux-headers-$(uname -r)

> Also if yes, Do I need to recompile the kernel after I have compiled the modules I have written ?

No